# Change the default directory for blogdown posts

Tags: r, blogdown

Posts for the Hugo theme I am using are in the `/content/blog` directory, whereas the default for new posts created with `blogdown::new_post()` is the `/content/post` directory.

From looking at the function definition, there is a global option to change the directory new posts are saved to (the help indicates this, too):

```
new_post(title, kind = "default", open = interactive(), 
    author = getOption("blogdown.author"), categories = NULL, 
    tags = NULL, date = Sys.Date(), file = NULL, slug = NULL, 
    subdir = getOption("blogdown.subdir", "post"), ext = getOption("blogdown.ext", 
        ".md"))
```

It looks like if I changed `getOption("blogdown.subdir", "post")` to `getOption("blogdown.subdir", "blog")`, then this might do the trick, but how can I do this so that it would be the default for all posts?

Comment: See `?options` for details on getting and setting options. You could add an `options` line to your R profile site file to run whenever you start R, [see here for an example](https://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `options(blogdown.subdir = 'blog')`. Please read [Section 1.4](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html) of the **blogdown** book for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the directions in Section 1.4 of the book - they're very helpful. When I restart my R session (or close and reopen RStudio), and then run `blogdown::new_post()`, it looks like it still defaults to the 'post' subdiretory. However, when I simply run the command `options(blogdown.subdir = 'blog')` and then `blogdown::new_post()`, the subdirectory is set to 'blog'. This makes this sound like the R profile file is not running. I posted a question about this in [R Studio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-check-that-r-profile-is-being-run-when-r-is-started/4122).