# blogdown - how do I specify which page a post will appear on

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown, toml

```
baseurl = "/"
relativeurls = false
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "A Hugo website"
theme = "hugo-lithium"
googleAnalytics = ""
disqusShortname = ""
ignoreFiles = ["\\.Rmd$", "\\.Rmarkdown", "_files$", "_cache$"]

[permalinks]
    post = "/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"

[[menu.main]]
    name = "Home"
    url = "/"
    weight = 1
[[menu.main]]
    name = "About"
    url = "/about/"
    weight = 2
[[menu.main]]
    name = "Blog"
    url = "/blog/"
    weight = 3

[params]
    description = "A website built through Hugo and blogdown."

    highlightjsVersion = "9.12.0"
    highlightjsCDN = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs"
    highlightjsLang = ["r", "yaml"]
    highlightjsTheme = "github"

    MathJaxCDN = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs"
    MathJaxVersion = "2.7.5"

[params.logo]
    url = "logo.png"
    width = 50
    height = 50
    alt = "Logo"
```

I'm using a slightly modified blogdown default `config.toml` with the `hugo-lithium` theme. Shown above. How do I make my 'Home' and 'About' pages static? And shift all my posts onto my 'Blog' page? I can't find anything in the [blogdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/) explaining this.

I did [discover this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063509/change-the-default-directory-for-blogdown-posts) that explains how to change the directory where the files are stored. This isn't what I want (I think). I want to know how to actually specify the page where `post`'s will go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hugo, the layout of the website mirrors the layout of the files in the content directory. So, if you have a blog post in `content/blog/my-cool-post.md`, it will show up as `https://example.com/blog/my-cool-post.html`

See [hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/organization/) for a bit more.

So for your about file, just place it directly in content as `content/about.md`